# How to search concatenated fields with MySQL in production and sqlite when testing with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a real hacky way of trying to get my tests to pass when I'm searching a concatenated field. For example, I store my users as first_name, last_name so when I come to search I would do something like this.

```
ExampleModel::where(DB::raw("concat(first_name, ' ', surname)"), 'LIKE', "%$term%")->get()
```

However, you get an error when testing (when you use sqlite) because it doesn't have the concat function. For this you would use something like this.

```
ExampleModel::where(DB::raw("first_name || ' ' || surname") , 'LIKE', "%$term%")->get()
```

Without having a check to see if your environment is testing, how would you go about searching for this that would work on both databases?

Comment: The problem is using different databases in production versus testing. There will be lots of differences, and you won't really know if something works just because it worked in testing.

Answer (score 0):

While not ideal, you can check your `.env` variables on the fly via `env("KEY")`, so you could wrap your functions in a check:

```
if(env("APP_ENV", "production") == "production"){
  ExampleModel::whereRaw("first_name || ' ' || surname LIKE '%".$term."%'");
} else {
  ExampleModel::whereRaw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', surname) LIKE '%".$term."%'");
}
```

In the case above, I'm assuming that `APP_ENV=production` in your `.env` file signifies that you're using `SQLite` instead of `MySQL`, and adjusting the query to handle.

Note that this is not perfect, as individual `Model` classes can define their own connection via `protected $connection = "mysql"; // sqlite, etc` and the above logic would not catch this.

Comment: @bencarter78 This is a solution to your question, without any doubts... But according to best practices, your db engine should match in both dev and production. Otherwise, you will be fighting to match all dependencies across different environments. There are tons of problems, that can emerge. So the idea is to move to mysql in dev to match your production. Why not? Mysql installation is super simple on all platforms, and it will solve your problem in the beginning...